# How to launch a ClickOnce app from Foxpro?

Tags: clickonce, visual-foxpro

I need to launch a ClickOnce application from a FoxPro 7 application. I know ClickOnce apps are deployed using file and folder names that are long combinations of letters and numbers which change frequently. I know I need to invoke the appref-ms file and it seems like, in vb.Net, you can get the path to the appref-ms file but I'm not sure if you can do that in FoxPro and if it's possible then how it could be accomplished.

I would very much appreciate any thoughts or insights on this issue.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at:
   [Using ClickOnce to Deploy Visual FoxPro Applications](http://www.codemag.com/article/0703072)

Yes, the article is about VFP9, it might be applicable to VFP7.

Good Luck

Comment: I'm not trying to deploy a Foxpro app with Clickonce. I have an existing Foxpro app and I'm trying to start/launch a vb.Net ClickOnce app programmatically from within Foxpro.

Comment: I know nothing about "ClickOnce", but, in general, when you want to launch the 'external' application from VFP you use   ShellExecute()